# Why can't I just build an array without assigning it to anything?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Why can't I just build an array without assigning it to anything but I can do that with a class?

```
new int[]{1,2,3};
new Date();
```

Line one gives an error. Line two is OK. Why do those two similar statements behave differently?

Comment: To put it simply, the [java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) gives a list of what is a valid statement. `new int[]{1,2,3};` is none of them, `new Date();` is an `ExpressionStament`, more precisely a `ClassInstanceCreationExpression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer (as others already commented): the spec doesn't accept it as a valid statement.

But why?

The rationale behind that specification is that this array construction `new int[]{1,2,3};` is useless. There is no way that any piece of your code can reference the array, so it immediately becomes garbage. And the array construction in itself doesn't have any useful side effects.

On the other hand, a constructor call like `new Date();` can potentially store a reference to the `Date` being constructed in some registry, or it can do some important work inside the constructor, or it can aven contain an endless loop. (Whether any of these is a good idea from a software engineering point of view, is questionable).

While the standard `Date` class doesn't do any of these things, the compiler can't know that. So the language designers decided that there might be legitimate usages of that code pattern und thus allowed class instantiation, but not array instantiation as a statement of its own.